# Find the last number out in a circle

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a circle and in that i have certain numbers say 11,12,13,14,15 and if the user passes input as 3
[image: find the final member]

Please refer the image above.
case 1. I have number 11,12,13,14,15 and user passed 3 so starting from 11 i would be getting 3 at 13 so i want to delete 13.

case 2: after deleting 13 again i should start at 14. If I start at 14 I would getting 3 at 11 and I want to delete 11.

Like this I want to continue and get the final number out. I have tried but some how I am failing at one point of time. Please look at my code.

```
public class CirularQue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = new int[5];

        int start = 4;

        int rear = -1;

        int front = -1;




        find(array, start, rear, front);

    }

    private static void find(int[] array, int start, int rear, int front) {

        int just = 4;
        while (just < 5 && just > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                // Filling up rear and front;
                if (rear == -1 && front == -1) {
                    rear = rear + 1;
                    front = front + 1;
                }

                // filling first time values
                if (just == 4) {
                    array[i] = i + 1;
                }
                // skip zeros 
                if(just<4 && array[i]==0){
                    i++;

                }

                // Moving forward increase the front
                front++;

                // replace with zero if we start and front are equal
                if (front == start && array[i] != 0) {
                    array[i] = 0;
                    front = 0;
                }
                // reset the value of i 
                if (i + 1 == array.length) {
                    i = -1;
                    just--;
                }

            }



        }
    }
}
```

Please help me how can I do this?

Comment: if your input numbers are not too big then you can use hashing for this purpose.

Comment: can you post your exception trace?

Comment: @Jack jay yes my input is big

Comment: Read about Josephus problem

Comment: What happens when the amount of numbers becomes less than your index? Say that you have `11 12 13 14 15`. Starting with `3` you get `11 12 14 15`, then you get `12 14 15`, then you get `12 14`... and then what? Do you start counting at `12` or at `14`?